# Android Problem: Textview onchange event

Tags: java, android, textview, onchange

i need to programm an android app, which has 4 textboxes.
If i write a char or number in 1 of this boxes all other boxes needs to be refreshed.
Now the point. I am using the onchange event, but there is a recursion and every onchange of the other boxes are executed. Is there a simple way without time or something to abort the other onchange events?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the OnFocusChangeListener for each EditView...

```
editview.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

So that when the control `hasFocus` it will call only the functionality you set in the onFocusChange method for only that EditView.

Answer (score 0):

Look into TextWatcher class and assigning one to your textviews